# my sql / php / pdo :strange error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

everything is ok , not a single flow in anywhere , its killing me :

this is the error :

SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

this is the code :

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=new_db';


$db = new PDO($dsn,'root');
```

and :

```
<?php
try {
    require_once 'pdo_connect.php';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Database Connection with PDO</title>
    <link href="../../styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Connecting with PDO</h1>
<?php if ($db) {
    echo "<p>Connection successful.</p>";
} elseif (isset($error)) {
    echo "<p>$error</p>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

what the h is wrong with xamp ? , i gave every folder anyone permision and root user az admin of it all

Comment: Does the database `new_db` exist? Why don't you submit a password?

Comment: yes , it doesnt have a password

Answer (score 0):

You've given your database handler a username but not a password.

```
$db = new PDO($dsn,'root','passwordhere');
```

see
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: my db hast have a password so :   
$db = new PDO($dsn,'root', '' );   
still give the same error